# Why am I getting these errors when trying to add a UIWebView to this ViewController header file?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

I was following the steps here: http://matt.might.net/articles/how-to-native-iphone-ipad-apps-in-javascript/

> Here are the bare bones steps to turning a web app into a native app:
>
> 1. Open XCode.
> 2. Create a new "View-based Application" iPhone project.
> 3. Move the files for your web app into the Resources folder in XCode,
>      but strip out the cache manifest. (You don't want the manifest
>      screwing things up, since everything is now local.)
> 4. Create a new instance variable, webView, inside the @interface
>      ViewController header file:    IBOutlet UIWebView* webView ;    //
>      IBOutlet means it's visible to Interface Builder.
> 5. and create a property:    @property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView
>      *webView;

Here is what I have thus far (ViewController.h):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

    IBOutlet UIWebView* webView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView;
@end
```

However on step 4 I am getting two errors in my ViewController header file:

[image]

> "cannot declare variable inside @interface or @protocol"
>
> and
>
> "iboutlet attribute can only be applied to instance variables or
>   properties"

So what am I doing wrong, or is that website tutorial wrong?

Note: I downloaded the sample project he had for iPhone and it worked, but I am following the tutorial so I can make an iPad version.

I am in XCode 4 and the error shows whether I do iOS 5 or iOS 4.3 doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing a couple of curly braces there:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    UIWebView *webView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

Comment: You would also need to add IBOutlet to your property statement.

Comment: Gah, I thought it was missing something... I guess I expected too much from XCode, thanks.

Comment: @Bill: yeah, I just noticed that too. The tutorial OP links to is a typical, incomplete and misleading iPhone tutorial.

Comment: @Ryan: `IBOutlet` is normally in the property rather than the instance variable declaration. I edited my answer to show this.

Comment: yes just came back to thread, before it said wait 7 minutes ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot the brackets; try to change your code to

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIWebView* webView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView;
@end
```